# Access raw file on GitHub Enterprise without user having to create token

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I have a repo with shell script and want to put single command to run it in readme file, like:

```
bash <(curl -L <path_to_raw_script_file>)
```

Raw file urls for GitHub Enterprise look like this: `https://raw.github.ibm.com/<user>/<repo>/<branch>/<path_to_file>?token=<token>`, where `<token>` is unique to the file and generated when accesing it via Raw button in repository or with `?raw=true` suffix in url.

The problem is, tokens get invalidated after few days/when file is updated and I wouldn't like to update mentioned command each time token becomes invalid.  Is there a way to deal with it?

I know there is a way for user to create personal token and use it to login to github from machine he's runnning script from, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible.

I was thinking of something like auto-generating that raw file url (since user reading the readme file on github surely does have access to the script located in the same repo), but I am not sure if that's possible.

Comment: [check out this method](https://gist.github.com/eliranmal/fe796bcd491d333f10742ab8f823c61e). no explicit tokens created, just basic auth

Answer (score 2):

No input, one-liner.

You can get this link by clicking the raw button in the GHE UI, just remove the token query param at the end.

```
curl -sfSO https://${USER}:${TOKEN}@${GHE_DOMAIN}/raw/${REPO_OWNER}/${REPO_NAME}/${REF}/${FILE}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll always need the tokens - however if you'd like to automate the process you can dynamically request tokens associated with a github Oauth app and not associated with any user profile.

https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.13/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/

Answer (score 0):

> I know there is a way for user to create personal token and use it to login to GitHub from machine he's runnning script from, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible.

Actually, using GCM (Git Credential Manager); the PAT will be provided when accessing the `raw.xxx` URL.

But only with [GCM v2.0.692](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.692) which supports those URLs. See [PR 599](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/pull/599).

> Fix GitHub Enterprise API URL for raw source code links
>
> This is a simple fix of [#598](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/issues/598) for GitHub Enterprise instances that use a `raw.` hostname prefix for raw source code links.
>
> I've verified this fix locally by swapping out the GitHub.dll that is used by Visual Studio.

So it now checks for '`raw.`' in the hostname and remove it to get the correct GHE API URL.